# Excel formula has no errors but it not working as expected

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet that returns if an item was completed on time or not. "A" column is either "Open" or "Closed". If the "A" column is "Open" then I want to return a blank cell. If the "A" column is "Closed" then it needs to calculate dates in column "B" and "X" to see if it was on time or not. The first part of the formula is returning blanks as it should. The two "IF(AND" statements that follow seem to be causing all cells in column "A" that are "Closed" to return a "No". Been digging at this for two days trying different ways of writing a formula with no success. The "X" column is calculated by adding two columns together...not sure if that makes a difference.

```
=IF(A2="Open"," ",IF(AND(A2="Closed",X2>=B2),"Yes",IF(AND(A2="Closed",X2<B2),"No")))
```

I expect if A2="Open" then it would return a blank cell. This is working as expected.

I expect if `A2="Closed"` then `X2>=B`2 would return a "Yes" and if `X2<B2` it would return a "No". There are no errors identified by Microsoft Excel.

Comment: `and if X2` ... please finish the sentence

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just wanted to say that, as far as I know, a `blank cell` means `""` but you are using a space char, `" "` and that is not a *blank cell*, but it is a *cell with a blank*.

Answer (score 2):

If A2 can only be "Open" or "Close",
syntax of your `If` should be :

```
=IF(A2="Open"," ",IF(X2>=B2,"Yes","No"))
```

Comment: This is a much simpler formula so thank you for that. The same problem still exists though. The formula returns a "No" regardless of the dates in cells X2 and B2 as long as A2 is "Closed"

Comment: I'll give the specific data below for reference.

A2 is "Closed"

B2 is "May 16, 2019"

X2 is "June 15, 2019"

So in this case it should return a "Yes" since X2>B2. B and X columns are both formatted the same (Date and type)

Comment: I've been able to narrow it down to the "X" column. I believe there is an issue because the "X" column is calculated by N2+W2. N2 being a date from the raw data pull and W2 being the formula =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CATEGORY 1 LINE STOPPER",L2)), "0", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CATEGORY 1",L2)), "0", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CATEGORY 2",L2)), "30", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CATEGORY 3",L2)), "60", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CATEGORY 4",L2)), "90",  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CATEGORY 5",L2)), "120")))))) but I'm not sure how having a date column calculated by a formula would be an issue.

Comment: @416NismoZ you should remove quotes around your numbers in W formula

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Excel is interpreting your dates as strings instead as dates. You can investigate by:

1. Open your formula in the editor and select `B2`.
2. While `B2` is selected, hit the `F9` key to show its value.
3. If it's a date value `F9` will convert it to a number like `41609`.
   If it's a string you'll get `"May 16, 2019"`.
4. Hit `CTRL-Z` to revert back to the original formula.
5. Repeat for `X2`.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the F9 tip. I haven't used formulas in excel in almost a decade and even then I was a novice. Much appreciated.

X2 returns "43631" so it's a date.

B2 turns from May 16, 2019 to 5/16/2019 when I double click it. This cell is raw data pulled from the system so there is no formula.

Comment: Finally figured it out. Column "B", which is the raw data pull, had something going on with the formatting. I had to click the column, then click the Data tab, then hit "Text to Columns", and hit next, next, then finish. Thanks to everyone for the quick assistance in trying to resolve this issue!